# android crop square video android compress to upload like instagram

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, compression, instagram

I had an android application which like instagram& now I want to crop selected video in square and compress it.
I tested ffmpeg with FFmpegAndroid by this command :

```
{"-y", "-ss", "" + (startTime / 1000), "-t", "" + ((endTime - startTime) / 1000), "-i", srcFilePath, "-vcodec", "libx264", "-crf", "35", dstFilePath}
```

The problem is ffmpeg run too mush slowly about 15 minute for just 30 sec video.

I also test silicompressorr but it just resize in standard video size and not compress final video.

How instagram cut, crop and scale down video files too fast?

please help me !!!

Edit

Ffmpef log for above is :

```
D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
02-27 20:29:36.402 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
02-27 20:29:36.402 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
02-27 20:29:36.402 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
02-27 20:29:36.402 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
02-27 20:29:36.402 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
02-27 20:29:36.403 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
02-27 20:29:36.403 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
02-27 20:29:36.403 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
02-27 20:29:36.403 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
02-27 20:29:36.403 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
02-27 20:29:37.526 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/9016-4EF8/movie/compress_video_new14.mp4':
02-27 20:29:37.527 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   Metadata:
02-27 20:29:37.527 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     major_brand     : isom
02-27 20:29:37.527 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     minor_version   : 512
02-27 20:29:37.527 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
02-27 20:29:37.528 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
02-27 20:29:37.528 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   Duration: 00:00:20.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 48020 kb/s
02-27 20:29:37.528 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m), 3840x2160, 47857 kb/s, 28.58 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
02-27 20:29:37.528 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     Metadata:
02-27 20:29:37.528 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg       rotate          : 90
02-27 20:29:37.528 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg       handler_name    : VideoHandler
02-27 20:29:37.528 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     Side data:
02-27 20:29:37.529 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
02-27 20:29:37.529 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 155 kb/s (default)
02-27 20:29:37.529 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     Metadata:
02-27 20:29:37.529 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg       handler_name    : SoundHandler
02-27 20:29:37.541 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg [swscaler @ 0xf47ef000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
02-27 20:29:37.594 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg [swscaler @ 0xf47e4000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
02-27 20:29:37.594 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.
02-27 20:29:37.594 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
02-27 20:29:37.594 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf506d400] using cpu capabilities: none!
02-27 20:29:37.674 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf506d400] profile High, level 3.1
02-27 20:29:37.674 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg [libx264 @ 0xf506d400] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
02-27 20:29:37.674 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/compress_video_new21.mp4':
02-27 20:29:37.674 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   Metadata:
02-27 20:29:37.674 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     major_brand     : isom
02-27 20:29:37.674 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     minor_version   : 512
02-27 20:29:37.674 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
02-27 20:29:37.675 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
02-27 20:29:37.675 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     Metadata:
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg       handler_name    : VideoHandler
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     Side data:
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg       unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 155 kb/s (default)
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg     Metadata:
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg       handler_name    : SoundHandler
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg Stream mapping:
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
02-27 20:29:37.676 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
02-27 20:29:38.359 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.16 bitrate=   2.3kbits/s speed=0.247x    
02-27 20:29:39.053 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=    4 fps=2.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.27 bitrate=   1.4kbits/s speed=0.197x    
02-27 20:29:39.752 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=    7 fps=3.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.35 bitrate=   1.1kbits/s speed=0.173x    
02-27 20:29:40.466 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   10 fps=3.6 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=   0.8kbits/s speed=0.167x    
02-27 20:29:40.990 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   12 fps=3.6 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.52 bitrate=   0.7kbits/s speed=0.159x    
02-27 20:29:41.672 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   15 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.63 bitrate=   0.6kbits/s speed=0.16x    
02-27 20:29:42.408 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   18 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.72 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s speed=0.153x    
02-27 20:29:42.917 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   20 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.80 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s speed=0.154x    
02-27 20:29:43.660 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   23 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.89 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s speed=0.149x    
02-27 20:29:44.392 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   26 fps=3.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.99 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s speed=0.149x    
02-27 20:29:44.904 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   28 fps=3.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.06 bitrate=   0.4kbits/s speed=0.147x    
02-27 20:29:45.467 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   30 fps=3.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.12 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=0.145x    
02-27 20:29:46.014 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   32 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.19 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=0.143x    
02-27 20:29:46.533 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   34 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.25 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=0.142x    
02-27 20:29:47.094 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   36 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.33 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=0.142x    
02-27 20:29:47.681 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   38 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.40 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=0.14x    
02-27 20:29:48.191 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   40 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.48 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s speed=0.142x    
02-27 20:29:48.752 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   42 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.57 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=0.142x    
02-27 20:29:49.531 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   45 fps=3.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.68 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.142x    
02-27 20:29:51.327 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   46 fps=3.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.74 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.128x    
02-27 20:29:52.108 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   49 fps=3.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.83 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=2 drop=0 speed=0.127x    
02-27 20:29:52.755 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   51 fps=3.4 q=29.0 size=      70kB time=00:00:01.89 bitrate= 301.9kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=0.126x    
02-27 20:29:53.826 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   52 fps=3.2 q=29.0 size=      93kB time=00:00:01.93 bitrate= 391.3kbits/s dup=3 drop=0 speed=0.12x    
02-27 20:29:54.884 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   54 fps=3.1 q=29.0 size=     117kB time=00:00:01.97 bitrate= 482.4kbits/s dup=4 drop=0 speed=0.115x    
02-27 20:29:55.448 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   55 fps=3.1 q=29.0 size=     121kB time=00:00:02.04 bitrate= 484.1kbits/s dup=4 drop=0 speed=0.115x    
02-27 20:29:55.643 12094-12116/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor I/MediaPlayer: message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
02-27 20:29:56.328 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   57 fps=3.1 q=29.0 size=     146kB time=00:00:02.08 bitrate= 571.8kbits/s dup=5 drop=0 speed=0.112x    
02-27 20:29:57.838 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   58 fps=2.9 q=29.0 size=     165kB time=00:00:02.12 bitrate= 633.4kbits/s dup=5 drop=0 speed=0.106x    
02-27 20:29:58.733 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   60 fps=2.9 q=29.0 size=     189kB time=00:00:02.19 bitrate= 707.6kbits/s dup=6 drop=0 speed=0.104x    
02-27 20:29:59.497 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   61 fps=2.8 q=29.0 size=     194kB time=00:00:02.23 bitrate= 712.0kbits/s dup=6 drop=0 speed=0.102x    
02-27 20:30:00.706 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   63 fps=2.7 q=29.0 size=     220kB time=00:00:02.29 bitrate= 782.9kbits/s dup=7 drop=0 speed=0.0999x    
02-27 20:30:02.546 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   64 fps=2.6 q=29.0 size=     240kB time=00:00:02.34 bitrate= 840.0kbits/s dup=7 drop=0 speed=0.0942x    
02-27 20:30:03.278 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   66 fps=2.6 q=29.0 size=     265kB time=00:00:02.38 bitrate= 908.4kbits/s dup=8 drop=0 speed=0.0932x    
02-27 20:30:03.877 12094-12094/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor D/BHUVNESH: Progress command : ffmpeg frame=   67 fps=2.6 q=29.0 size=     270kB time=00:00:02.44 bitrate= 902.0kbits/s dup=8 drop=0 speed=0.0936x
```

Comment: Show the complete ffmpeg log from your command.

Comment: Hi. I edited question and add ff mpeg log.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/30601802/192373 solution instead

Comment: @MehdiShojaeian Your x264 was compiled with `--disable-asm` causing you to get the message `[libx264 @ 0xf506d400] using cpu capabilities: none!` which indicates that your CPU is likely not being fully utilized. This is a common occurrence among `ffmpeg` users on Android due to using a popular mis-configured third-party compile script. Also, your x264 is old. If you want to disregard this issue, and still pursue `ffmpeg` as a solution, the easiest change you can make is to add `-preset ultrafast`, but compression efficiency will suffer.

Comment: you said if I compile ffmpeg native code for my project I get fast result ?

Comment: @MehdiShojaeian Sorry, I didn't see your comment quickly because you didn't include my name so there was no notification. If you compile x264 without `--disable-asm` you will see an improvement in encoding speed. You will need to recompile ffmpeg as well but you can use your existing configure options.